# Rubyでundefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

Cloud9環境でRubyを使用して仮想通貨の自動売買botを作成していたところ以下のエラーを表示して困っています。

＜エラー内容＞

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

＜該当部ソース＞

```
#注文状況の確認
def order_status
    flag = 0
    bbcc = Bitbankcc.new(API_KEY, API_SEC)
    while flag == 0 do
        response =  bbcc.read_active_orders('xrp_jpy')
        response_hash = JSON.parse(response)
        response_data = response_hash["data"]
        response_order = response_data["orders"]
        if response_order[0]["status"] == "FULLY_FILLED" then
            price = response_order[0]["price"]
            flag = 1
        end
    sleep(0.1)
    end
    return price
end
```

＜やりたいこと＞

`response_order[0]["status"]`の中身が`"FULLY_FILLED"`になるまでループさせたいだけです。
response_orderの中身は下のようになっています。

```
{"order_id"=>9408346, "pair"=>"xrp_jpy", "side"=>"sell", "type"=>"limit", "start_amount"=>"10.000000", "remaining_amount"=>"10.000000", "executed_amount"=>"0.000000", "price"=>"130.0000", "average_price"=>"0.0000", "ordered_at"=>1517417353070, "status"=>"UNFILLED"}
```

Rubyどころかプログラミング自体が初心者で、なんとか独学で頑張ってきましたがお手上げ状態です。

稚拙なコードでお恥ずかしいのですがアドバイス頂ければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nilに対して[]を使ってアクセスしようとしたら出るerrorですね。

```
> nil[0]
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

8～11行までに[]を使っていじろうとしていますが、そのうちのどれかで変数がnilのままいじろうとして怒られてます。

例えば、Hashから[]を使って値を取り出そうとされてますが、対象のkeyが無い場合nilが返ります。
恐らく、key名の間違いか想定した構造のresponseが返ってきてないのではないかと思います。

これ以上は、実際にresponseで返って来た値が無いと回答できないと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
確認したところ稀にAPIからデータが取得出来ていないことがわかりました。
取得したデータがnilかどうか判定することで回避することが出来ました。